# Find array key value from another key of array in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to find one key of array value in another key in the same array.

Following is my array output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1187
            [user_id] => 168            
            [content] => Thanks a lot man            
            [item_id] => 1182
            [secondary_item_id] => 1186

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1186
            [user_id] => 222
            [content] => Great Post
            [item_id] => 1182
            [secondary_item_id] => 1182

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1183
            [user_id] => 185
            [content] => Amazing first post
            [item_id] => 1182
            [secondary_item_id] => 1182
         )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1184
            [user_id] => 179
            [content] => Wonder Post
            [item_id] => 1182
            [secondary_item_id] => 1182
         )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1185
            [user_id] => 168
            [content] => Rocking Thanks
            [item_id] => 1182
            [secondary_item_id] => 1183

        )

)
```

Here you can see `id` **&** `secondary_item_id` key in array, So I want to find which array id is used in secondary_item_id key of array or how can i search id key of array is used in secondary_item_id key in array.

For example.. you can see `'Great Post'` id key is used in `'Thanks a lot man'` secondary_item_id key of array. So i want to search which array key id is used in secondary_item_id key of array.

I have tried using following way but not working.

```
$commentData = array();

foreach ($commentQuery as $key => $value) {
     if(array_search($value['id'], array_column($commentQuery, 'secondary_item_id'))){
                echo "list Found".$value['id'];
     }else{
                echo "list not  Found".$value['id'];
    }
}
```

It's only return `list not  Found1187`.

Comment: If you have control of the format of the output array consider changing the keys to be the id itself, then you can easilly access any item by its id without having to loop through. Additionally if your current method returns index 0 as the result of array_search (which it looks like it would for 1187), it wil resolve false.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this works for you

```
$ch=true;
foreach ($commentQuery as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($commentQuery as $key2 => $value2) {
      if($value2['id']==$value['secondary_item_id']){
        $ch=false;
        echo "list Found ".$value['id']." in array key ".$key2;
        break;
      }
    }
     if($ch){
      echo "list not  Found".$value['id'];
     }
    $ch=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-only single foreach loop using**

$search_column variable is out of  foreach because every time this sentence execute and your code execute slowly

```
$search_column = array_column($commentQuery, 'secondary_item_id');
foreach ($commentQuery as $key => $value) {
    $search = null;
    $search = array_search($value['id'], $search_column);
    if (gettype($search) == 'integer') {
        echo "list Found" . $value['id'];
    } else {
        echo "list not  Found" . $value['id'];
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```